# Understanding Exchange Link for User-Created Wallets on CEX

Tags: blockchain, web3js, cryptocurrency

I'm looking into how user-created wallets (let's call it Wallet A) on centralized exchanges (CEX) connect to the exchange's hot wallet. Specifically, when funds are deposited into Wallet A, they seem to be automatically directed to the CEX's hot wallet.

My main question is: How can users verify that Wallet A's address is associated with the exchange's hot wallet? Additionally, if possible, I'm curious about the process by which the created wallet is automatically linked to the hot wallet.

Your insights or explanations on these specific aspects would be appreciated.

Thank you

Google and asked people

Answer (score 0):

Cross-verify the provided deposit address with information available through secure communication channels provided by the exchange.

If you have made previous deposits, compare the deposit address from the current transaction with addresses used in the past.